# Possible to add support for MySQL?

Tags: package

Would the OS be able to support installation and use of MySQL anytime soon? Apt package manager stated it wasn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, but [How to install MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) will take you through the steps, just make sure to update (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`) your system before installing mysql.

I also recomend MySQL Workbench, it just makes your life easier...
[image]